# How to mock a Kubernetes API endpoint that returns a socket?

Tags: javascript, api, sockets, kubernetes, mocking

I am mocking some endpoints of the Kubernetes API in a mock server for some integration tests and got stuck in the implementation of the endpoint `/apis/batch/v1/watch/namespaces/{namespace}/jobs?watch=true` ([doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#job-v1-batch), need to search for `batch/v1/watch` in the page). The client uses [this](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/blob/master/src/watch.ts#L80-L139) method to make a GET request and keep the connection open to receive events related to Job resources. Apparently, it handles a 'socket' event.

I implemented a simple mock endpoint that returns the data I want, but I get this error when the request is made:

```bash
Error: socket hang up
    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:691:14)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:466:23)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:538:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

How should this mock be implemented? Do I need to return a socket? How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to my own question: after some attempts, all I needed to do was to use `res.write()` with a string that ends with a line break character, like this:

```js
import express from 'express';

const TIME_BETWEEN_EVENTS = 500; // Milliseconds
const app = express();

app.get('/apis/batch/v1/watch/namespaces/:namespace/jobs', (_, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    Connection: 'keep-alive',
  });

  console.log('Client connected to Jobs watch endpoint');
  let jobEventsSent = 0;

  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (jobEventsSent < 3) {
      console.log('Sending data to Jobs watcher');
      res.write(
        Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({ type: 'ADDED', object: { /* Job Resource */ } }) + '\n'),
      );
      jobEventsSent++;
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
  }, TIME_BETWEEN_EVENTS);

  res.socket.on('close', () => {
    console.log('Client disconnected from Jobs watch endpoint');
    if (interval) clearInterval(interval);
  });
});
```

The code above keeps the connection alive event after all the messages have been sent. To close the connection, it is necessary to call `res.end()`;